# Python - Fetching either max or min of two colums based on value in another column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Suppose have dataframe with following data

```
key score1 score2 count
1    0.87   0.13   0
2    0.67   0.33   1
3    0.46   0.54   1
4    0.28   0.72   0
5    0.41   0.59   1
```

what is the shortest way of finding min[score1, score2] if count == 0 or max[score1, score2] when count > 0?

present solution have is

```
data['mini']=data[[score1, score2]].min(axis=1)
data['maxi']=data[[score1, score2]].max(axis=1)
data['fin_score']= data['mini'].where(data['count']==0, data['maxi'])
```

is there way it could be made more crisp (in 1/2 commands), like in excel this would be as below and then just drag formula across all rows

```
=IF(count>0,MAX(B2:C2),MIN(B2:C2))
```

result would like this

```
key score1 score2 count fin_score
1    0.87   0.13   0       0.13
2    0.67   0.33   1       0.67
3    0.46   0.54   1       0.54
4    0.28   0.72   0       0.28
5    0.41   0.59   1       0.59
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel's IF function's equivalent for arrays is [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['fin_score'] = np.where(df['count']==0, df[['score1', 'score2']].min(axis=1), df[['score1', 'score2']].max(axis=1))

df
Out: 
   key  score1  score2  count  fin_score
0    1    0.87    0.13      0       0.13
1    2    0.67    0.33      1       0.67
2    3    0.46    0.54      1       0.54
3    4    0.28    0.72      0       0.28
4    5    0.41    0.59      1       0.59
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need extra values stored in lines?

```
data['fin_score'] = (max if data['count'] else min)(map(lambda k: data['score' + k], ('1', '2')))
```